# new Popup window in JavaFX over a main window with multiple .fxml files and multiple controllers for them

Tags: controller, window, javafx-2, fxml

I read this article [JavaFX 2.0 subwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997851/javafx-2-0-subwindow)

But I need a way to do this same thing, but with multiple .fxml files and java controllers for them.

Basically pushing a button will bring up a Popup window where a user can modify settings. And the layout for both the main window and the Popup window are in their own .fxml files and have their own Java controller files.

The button is going to create an instance of a class which will read the properties set in the Popup window. That is what I am aiming for.

Right now I have my main window. Its .fxml file and its controller.
I have my secondary .fxml file and its java controller too.
But I am struggling to bring up this new window.

Comment: Re-apply the same logic of loading and showing of the main fxml to the secondary fxml within main controller.

Comment: That's a little too vague of an answer for me. That also assumes I knew how it worked in the first place.

Comment: [code]@Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
              
                FractalParticle fp1= new FractalParticle();
                root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem("Fractal Particle "+ Long.toString(fpcount))  );
                fpcount++;
                Parent fp=    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FractalParticleDesign.fxml"));
        
                Stage stage;
                Scene scene = new Scene(fp);
                stage.setTitle("Particles!");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();   [/code]

Comment: well I tried to give that the code wrapper, anyways it fails  with overridden method does not throw Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java Magazine](http://mailings1.texterity.com/portal/wts/cemciSid2C-LeemveLDrs76ize4Da4l1HG_2QHNT10Nc) for Nov/Dec has a good article on a JavaFX project with multiple windows, using a Spring framework to inject the dependencies for you.