# Architecture of a multiple-windowed JavaFX 8 Application

Tags: java, architecture, javafx

I'm building a multi-window and multi-module simulation application, and I use JavaFX for GUI.

From what I understood, to make a JavaFX project run, you need to run `Application.launch( MyApplicationSubclass.class )` and use the primary stage given in the `start(Stage primaryStage)` method to get started. Everything in the `start` method and beyond happens in a JavaFX thread.

My app is a multi-moduled application. Today, a `Main` class bootstraps the program and launches several modules (which are distinct Maven modules), including the one in charge of the GUI. In the beginning (when I designed the current architecture), I planned to create only one window. So, once loaded, the GUI module would make the `Application.launch( MyOnlyMainWindow.class )` call, and everything would work fine.

Today, I'd like to add a console window, launched before any module, and used to "live-log" the application (by redirecting the System.out stream, between other things, into a TextFlow). But with the architecture previously described, it's impossible, because if I want ot keep the `Application.launch()` call in the GUI module, then I can't make it in the Console window, which is not a part of the GUI module. It would also be impossible to add another GUI module that would manage another set of window.

So I can think of two and a half ways to solve this:

- Centralize, somehow, the `Application.launch()` call so that it is available to every class that would need it. I don't know how to do it though.
- Change the `Main` class to heritate from javaFx Application class. But wouldn't that make me execute all my module instanciations into the JavaFX Thread? I would guess this is a bad way of doing things. Or even, if I decide to create other threads for module instanciation, those threads would have been created in the JavaFX thread.
- (Use Swing for the Console Window, though it does not actually solve my problem a viable way... What if I need to create another window in another GUI  module?)

**What would be a viable way of creating and managing a multiple window application with JavaFX? How could I, for instance, centralize the JavaFX `Application.launch()` calls?**

Or, in other words

**Is it a good practice to decentralize the JavaFX `Application` implementation in a module and launch the module from the `main()` class, or is it better to implement it in the `main()` class, even if I try to make my program modular?**

Comment: Why do think that creating a new window on the same `JavaFX Thread` is a bad idea? You can create as many [Stages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) you need in the same thread.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of: [JavaFX 2.0 subwindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997851/javafx-2-0-subwindow)

Comment: @ItachiIchiha That was not my main issue. My problem would be either to access this thread, or to instanciate all the modules in this thread, if i respectively create it in the GUI module, or heritate the `Application` class with `Main`.

Comment: @jewelsea Not really. My question is focused on the architecture more than the actual method to class or objects to create. What would be the best strategy to create multiple windows in (or out of) several modules using only one sub-Application object. I hope it's clearer now, if not, I will try to edit my post.

Comment: There is no architecture required to create multiple windows, you can see from the answer I linked that it can be done in a single line of code.  You will need to edit your post to get further assistance, you may need to include sample code (perhaps even an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and point out what you think is wrong with the code and design you have, then perhaps somebody could advise you how to fix or improve it.

Comment: @jewelsea I'll try to be more explicit !

Comment: Are you confusing the `Application` and `Stage` classes somehow? `Application` represents the entire JavaFX application. You should only have one `Application` subclass instance loaded in a JVM, and you are only allowed to call `Application.launch(...)` once; calling it a second time will generate a runtime exception. `Stage`, by contrast, represents a window. You can create as many of these as you like and show/hide them as needed (but you must do so on the FX Application Thread). I would just migrate your startup to `start(...)`, and launch non-UI "modules" in background threads.

Comment: @James_D Yes I understood the difference. But I wanted to keep the `Application.launch()` call in the GUI module, and not in the `main()` of my application. Turns out this call is not returning until all JavaFX windows are closed, so even if I keep it in the GUI module, it will block my main thread (and thus the creation of new modules). So I might have to create a full JavaFX application (`launch()` call made in `main()`), and create a thread to build the modules. But it breaks modularity (as the application will be designed in JavaFX in mind, and not only the GUI module).